# want to apply explicit wait 'invisibilityOfElementLocated' on child window handler?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Want to apply explicit wait 'invisibilityOfElementLocated' on child window handler?.

using below code i am able to iterate between windows handler.

```
String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
Set<String> handles =  driver.getWindowHandles();
for(String windowHandle  : handles)  {
if(!windowHandle.equals(parentWindow))    {
     driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);

     // <!--want wait till child window get closed

    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow); //cntrl to parent window
    }
   }
```

i want apply explicit wait on child window till child window get closed.

any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Vipin

Answer (score 0):

The idea I have to solve that, is search something into the new Window and wait for the invisibility (when the object disappear).

I usually use this:

```
new FluentWait<>(driver).withTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)));
```

Where:

1. `driver` is your driver.
2. `xpath` something inside the new window